# "Some students in this class grew up in the same town as at least two other students in this class.”

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

> Some students in this class grew up in the same town as at least two other students in this class.

I'm thinking that I'm required to use the following information:

$T(x,y):$ student $x$ grew up in town $y$ 
$C(x):$ student $x$ is in this class.

I think "some students" means $∃x C(x).$ But my translation $$∃x C(x) T(x,y)$$ seems too naive. How is it possible to express "at least two other students" using quantifiers? What is a more accurate translation?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hint: "at least two" = "there exist x and there exist y such that x != y and A is true of x and of y"

Comment: Also make sure to express the "other" in the sentence in the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $D=\{ x: x$ is a person$\}$ be the domain consisting of all people. We also define the following predicate symbols...

$
\begin{array}{11}
Txy: & \text{$x$ grew up in the same town as $y$} \\
Cx: & \text{$x$ is in this class} \\
\end{array}
$

To translate your statement properly, there are at least three distinct students that need to be specified:

"Some students in this class [that is, at least one student in this class, whom we call $x$] grew up in the same town as at least two other students in this class [whom we call $y$ and $z$]."

It is necessary to specify $y \neq z$ because there are *at least two* students, and it is necessary to specify $x \neq y$ and $x \neq z$ because there are at least two *other* students.

$$ \exists x \exists y \exists z[Cx \wedge Cy \wedge Cz \wedge x \neq y \wedge x \neq z \wedge y \neq z \wedge Txy \wedge Txz] $$

Comment: Thank you for your help! One question I have is where does the z come in?

Comment: see my post above, which i have edited to answer your question